# Very Simple RegEx Expression Not Working

Tags: php, regex

I have a long string which I would like to sanitize against a whitelist using PHP's `preg_replace`. This data is already somewhat encoded and is all in ANSI, no need to worry about Unicode here.

What I want to do is convert any character outside of a specific whitelist to a dash.

```
preg_replace("[^0-9A-Za-z/\-_.?=:]", "-", $input);
```

My understanding is that the `[]` is a character set, I then write the characters I want to allow, no escaping needed here, with a `^` at the beginning to negate it.

But it doesn't work: the string comes out of `preg_replace` exactly as it went in. If I put in a `%`, the `%` comes out, and I don't want that, I want it converted to a dash.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write the [regex delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
preg_replace("#[^0-9A-Za-z/\-_.?=:]#", "-", $input);
```

OR better:

```
preg_replace("#[^\w/.?=:-]#", "-", $input);
```

Comment: Amazing! That's fixed it, thanks so much. I'll mark as answer when I can.